# Cambio de divisa en Libreoffice calc 5.4

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Tengo una hoja de cálculo en LibreOffice `LibreOffice 5.4.6.2 40` en la que trabajo con coronas checas. Quiero que convertir algunas celdas a euros, pero no he encontrado ninguna extensión,  ni ningún tutorial que funcione. Pues los servicios que importaba con LibreOffice me mostraban tablas que no eran relevantes o no podá manejarlas. He segido el siguiente tutorial sin éxito:
https://albertoroura.com/tener-el-cambio-de-moneda-actualizado-en-tiempo-real-en-una-celda-de-libreoffice-calc/

Comment: Si bies podría ser útil el enlace al tutorial que has intentado seguir, las preguntas deben ser autocontenidas, es decir, debes indicar en la pregunta lo que has intentando y si ha ocurrido algún mensaje de error indicar este textualmente.

Comment: Eso es lo que he puesto

Comment: Si te refieres a " He segido el siguiente tutorial sin éxito: https://albertoroura.com/tener-el-cambio-de-moneda-actualizado-en-tiempo-real-en-una-celda-de-libreoffice-calc/" eso no cumple con la premisa que la pregunta sea autocontenida. Al menos deberías incluir los pasos más relevantes y el resultado que has obtenido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final, he dado con la tecla. Básicamente es seguir los pasos del tutorial, pero usando la web del Banco Nacional Checo, que me devuelve una tabla sólo con números, y se hace mucho más cómodo trabajar con ella. El resto de servicios me daban problemas con las tablas.